# Is it really a Mitzvah to greet a fellow Jew?

Tags: mitzvah, bein-adam-lachavero, chesed-kindness

I would think that it would be good middot to be a mentsch and ask a fellow Jew "hello, how are you?", but is there really any Mitzvah to it? Or does it count as a Chesed?

Comment: Kesubos 111B https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111b.19?lang=bi&with=Commentary

Answer (score 6):

Yes, at the very least, it is a mitzvah of following the words of our sages ([Devarim 17:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.10?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) to greet a fellow Jew (or any individual) as the [Mishna Avos (4:20)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> רַבִּי מַתְיָא בֶן חָרָשׁ אוֹמֵר, הֱוֵי מַקְדִּים בִּשְׁלוֹם כָּל אָדָם - Rabbi Masya ben Charash said: Upon meeting people, be the first to extend greetings.

Even if it is "counted as chesed," that is also a mitzvah ([Rambam Aveilus 14:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Mourning.14.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Yoreh%20De%27ah&lang2=en)). The Chofetz Chaim in [Ahavas Chesed (3:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ahavat_Chesed%2C_Part_III.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) discusses many examples of the mitzvah of chesed one can accomplish by encouraging others through speech.

Wishing shalom to others and showing you care seem to fit both of these mitzvos.

Comment: "_Even if it is 'counted as chesed,' **that is also a mitzvah**._" (emphasis mine) Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: @TamirEvan See Rambam Aveilus 14:1 - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Mourning.14.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Yoreh%20De%27ah&lang2=en